# How to resolve inode overflow with important files on a digital ocean server?

Tags: linux, digital-ocean, inode

I have a site located at a digitalocean server. The site has too many inodes. I would like to remove some of them. If I run

```
df -h
```

I can see there are 5.6 gigabytes in use.

If I run

```
df -i
```

I can see there are 1310720 inodes. However, if I run

```
sudo find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

I can see less than 35000 results in total. So where the inodes are coming from and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question .... I suggest you take it to ServerFault or SuperUser. That said: you're not telling the whole story (what's the starting point *.* for your find, what's the directory structure underneath it?  How does it relate to what you see in df's output? ... )

Comment: I am searching from the root folder. There are many folders and subfolders. None of those contains many files.

Comment: A directory (even if empty) also holds an inode, so maybe your *-type f* is what's misleading you?

Comment: I do not know, I have very little knowledge about Linux, unfortunately.

Comment: Well ... how many empty directories do you have? Each one uses an inode.

Comment: Let me find out how to find out :)

Comment: @tink, the result of find . -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l is 8721

Comment: That doesn't really help. Inodes aren't per directory level, but per file system.